# How to find an average of a key with multiple values?

Tags: python, max, average

I'm trying to print out the averages in order of highest to lowest however the code I have so far does the average for each person however then I'm unable to print them out in order of highest to lowest. I tried using the `max` function however it doesn't work.

```
for usernames, valuesforusers in sorted(dictionary.items()):
            thefirstaveragevariable = sum(valuesforusers)/len(valueforusers)
            averageslistofdoom = []
            averageslistofdoom.append(average)
            print ("{} Scoreino ploxerino thankerino: {}".format(usernames,max(averagesofdoom)))
```

dictionary would like this:

```
Thomas Scored: 8
Louie Scored: 3
Thomas Scored: 4
Louie Scored: 5
Louie Scored: 2
```

The name being the key while the score is the value. If needed i can post the splitting loop.So a print out of dictionary would like this:

```
{'Louie Scored': [3, 5, 2], 'Thomas Scored': [8, 4]}
```

Comment: How does `d` look like? Could you post an example?

Comment: You can't have the same `Louie Scored` string as different keys of the same dictionary. Could you paste the output of `print dictionary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I'd do is creating an intermediate dictionary with the averages of your users and then show that sorted. You might want to take a look to what [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [sorted](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) do.

```
import operator

dictionary = {
    'Louie Scored': [3, 5, 2],
    'Thomas Scored': [8, 4]
}

averages = {}

for user_info, v in dictionary.items():
    average = float(sum(v))/len(v)
    averages[user_info] = average

sorted_averages = sorted(averages.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for user_name, average in sorted_averages:
    print ("{} average score {}".format(user_name, average))
```

Which outputs:

```
Thomas Scored average score 6.0
Louie Scored average score 3.33333333333
```

Something a tad shorter (to avoid the *middle* dictionary) would be doable by relying on the fact that when you have a `dict` and call [items()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) on that `dict`, you get 2-elements tuples where the first element of the tuple is the key (your *username*) and the second element is the value (the *username's scores*). When you call `sorted` with the `dictionary.items()`, the `lambda` is going to be receiving those 2-tuple elements, so in `lambda x`, that `x` will be a tuple where the first element (`x[0]` is the *username* and the second element, `x[1]` are the scores for that username):

```
dictionary = {
    'Louie Scored': [3, 5, 2],
    'Thomas Scored': [8, 4]
}

for username, values in sorted(dictionary.items(),
                               key=lambda x: (sum(x[1]) / len(x[1])), reverse=True):
    print "username: %s, values %s" % (username, sum(values) / len(values))
```

Which outputs:

```
username: Thomas Scored, values 6
username: Louie Scored, values 3
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me not only figure out the problem but then explaining it in such detail :)

Comment: Glad I helped. Have fun coding **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

use numpy ... also you must provide a key to sort by

```
import numpy as np
print sorted((username,np.average(values),values) for username, values in d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

the default sort will sort tuples based on their first element ... in this example it is their name.

you can make the first element the average instead, and then you would not need to provide a key

Comment: is there a way of not using the `lambada` function ?

Comment: sure write a non-lambda function, or use `operator.itemgetter` or put the average as the first value in the tuples ... instead of the second